# Describing something I've never been through

Tags: creative-writing, description

I have this young character who grows up to be very strong and powerful but while he was young he was still discovering how strong he was. This incident happened to a friend he's protective of. He tossed around the people who attacked his friend and almost killed one of them by breaking his rib cage. I wanted this to be a moment in his story that makes him always hold back in a fight. But I'm not good with emotions; could someone help?

Comment: Also he finds out about what he did to the one he broke  from a Person whose training him.